# JQuery function to display text on a timed interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an external JavaScript file that contains some calculations.  The results are put into an array.  I've written some 'get' functions to return the values of a passed in index value.  In my HTML file, I've written a function to display the array on a new line every 1 second.  Here is the code for that:

```
<script>
var showSequence = function (target, message, index, interval) {
    if(index < message.length) {
        $(target).append(message[index++]);
        setTimeout(function (){ showSequence(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
    }
}
</script>
```

I call it like:

```
    <body>  
<script>
    $function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < getArrayLength(); i++){
            showSequence('#calculations', getArrayValue(i) + '<br />', i, 1000);
        }               
    }
</script>
<h1>Fibonacci Calculation:</h1>
<p id='calculations'></p>
```

However I get an unexpected token { error.  Being new to JavaScript, I can't find a missing {.  Looking for a little help on this.

Comment: two things first the missing ; at the end of showSequence('#calculations', getArrayValue(i) + '<br />', i, 1000) then the $funciton() that I am not sure if its legal or not but might be another implementation I just did'nt knew about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  So I had to wait until JQuery was ready before I performed a set of functions.  I needed to replace:

```
    $(function(){ //Do Stuff here });
```

with:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { //Do Stuff here });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `(` for `$` at beginning of second function , and adding `())` to close of second function , to create and call an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression ("IIFE") . See [What is this (IIFE) construct in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-iife-construct-in-javascript) .

Alternatively , could remove `$` from beginning of second function , provide a `name` for the second function , and call the second function by `name` ; i.e.g.,

```
function runSequence(){
            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                showSequence('#calculations', arr, i, 1000)
            }               
        };
runSequence();
```

---

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var showSequence = function (target, message, index, interval) {
    if(index < message.length) {
        $(target).append(message[index++]);
        setTimeout(function (){ showSequence(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
    }
};
    // substituted `(` for `$` at beginning of function
    (function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            showSequence('#calculations', arr, i, 1000)
        }               
    }()) // added `())` at closing of function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Fibonacci Calculation:</h1>
<p id='calculations'></p>
```

Comment: It's a requirement to use JQuery. The $ signifies accessing the JQuery library. Removing said elements would eliminate JQuery wouldn't it? It would be pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you add the `$function()` ? It doesn't exist.
Just delete it and it will work I think

JS

```
//$function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < getArrayLength(); i++){
        showSequence('#calculations', getArrayValue(i) + '<br />', i, 1000);
    }               
//}
```

EDIT : I think I understand what you tried to do

JS

```
$(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < getArrayLength(); i++){
        showSequence('#calculations', getArrayValue(i) + '<br />', i, 1000);
    }               
})
```

Comment: It's a requirement to use JQuery.  The $ signifies accessing the JQuery library.  Removing said elements would eliminate JQuery wouldn't it?  It would be pure JavaScript?

Comment: sorry forgot to include you in the post.

Comment: I edited my answer. I think you want to use `$(function(){});` and that is right to use but `$function()`, I think it's impossible because it means you want to invoke the function named `$function` and you never declared it. Or you need to create this function like this function `$function(){
    //your code
}` then you can invoke a function `$function()` and there's no error

Comment: *Or you need to create this function like this `function $function(){
    //your code
}`